# I can't get Selenium radiobutton access, given a error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Id defined for radiobuttons

```
 <tr _ngcontent-icx-c221="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""><td _ngcontent-icx-c221="" style="width: 4rem; border-width: 1px; text-align: center;"><div _ngcontent-icx-c221="" class="flex justify-content-start align-items-center ng-star-inserted"><p-radiobutton _ngcontent-icx-c221="" name="produktRisiko" class="mr-1 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-reflect-name="produktRisiko" ng-reflect-input-id="produktRisiko_7" ng-reflect-value="8" ng-reflect-model="4"><div ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" class="p-radiobutton p-component"><div class="p-hidden-accessible"><input type="radio" id="produktRisiko_7" name="produktRisiko" value="8" aria-checked="false"></div><div ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" class="p-radiobutton-box"><span class="p-radiobutton-icon"></span></div></div><!--bindings={}--></p-radiobutton><span _ngcontent-icx-c221="" class="flex align-items-center">6</span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--></td><td _ngcontent-icx-c221="" style="border-width: 1px;"> Consequential damage on main parts, (repairable on location with </td></tr>
```

And my code is:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("produktRisiko_7"))).click();
```

Error:

```
 Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: produktRisiko_7 (tried for 50 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

Comment: In the future, copy and paste the text rather than posting a picture. What I saw there was `"produktRisiko_7"`, but I assume `_6`exists. Without looking at the DOM, it is hard to figure out what the problem is. You need to explain what you mean by "can't get access". For example, what is the error you are getting? Maybe the radio button is disabled, so it never gets into a "clickable" state. Only you know the answer to this question.

Comment: the ID produktRisiko_7 is always the same?

Comment: Use `visibilityOfElement` instead of `elementToBeClickable`

Comment: @NandanA if the intent is to click the radio button, using `visibilityOfElement` is not only pointless, it is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: To meet the expected condition, it has to be false before start waiting. So try `driver.findElement(By.id("produktRisiko_7")).click();` instead.

Comment: Same question as @itronic1990 everytime you access the application does the element always have the _ID_ as `produktRisiko_7`

Comment: @DebanjanB yes element always have the ID

Comment: @pburgr I try but same error

Comment: Then check if there are more elements with the same id. If not debug your code and check if the element is clickable manualy during runtime.

Comment: @sdev Question wasn't about _element always have the ID_ or not. We can see the element have ID. The question is: _Everytime you access the application, is the ID always the same_?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is what I suspected. Your radio button is not clickable because it is disabled (hidden). Your radio button element is surrounded by a div that is hidden:

```
<div class="p-hidden-accessible">
    <input type="radio" id="produktRisiko_7" name="produktRisiko" value="8" aria-checked="false">
</div>
```

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but you got to figure out why this `div` is hidden. Hopefully this give you some insight, but you need to explain your problem better. What are you trying to do? Can you actually see the button on the page?  If you cannot see the radio button on the page, you should not attempt to interact with the component using some backdoor mechanism (i.e. invoking a JavaScript command) because the purpose of these tests, I assume, is to test human interaction.

Comment: Yes I can see and use the radiobuttons. I think the problem is that it is hidden as you say. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with the following structure. Thank you for your attention

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('produktRisiko_7').click();");
```